# How to insert VAT Number in a customer using api in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

i have a doubt i'm using the rest admin api for a store shopify integration and im currently with this issue. My store country is in Portugal so in that order the vat number is required. If i may i'm using the api to create an order and using the parameter properties to pass trough the vat: for example:

```
orderProduct = { "order": { "lineitems": [ { "variantid": variantId, "quantity": 1, "name": "carlos vieira", "title": "Big Brown Bear Boots", "price": 74.99, "properties": [ { "name": "VAT", "value": "219125272" } ], }
```

But i wanna ask if there is a field to apply vat number directly to customer in a call in rest admin api or store front or graph ql.

This is crucial because i want to create invoices using an app and i can't see the vat number... in the invoice...

http://recordit.co/bKilwU6eDH

Many thanks in advance Carlos Vieira

Comment: I don't know if there is a direct way of creating an order an modifying customer's field at the same time but you can definitely call customers api to add VAT in note field of customer

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i already found a solution.
I have a call with the creators of the invoice plugin and they told me to add this parameters in an creation of order.

```
"note_attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "vat_number",
                    "value": "PT00000000"
                }
            ],
```

this parameter will add to order as additional details
then it will be taken by invoice plugin.

thanks
carlos vieira